# Unable to resolve host address while using wget

Tags: virtualbox

While doing wget google.com, the response would be "Unable to resolve host address". This would be the same for any IP provided. Is it because of using Virtual Box and any changes need to be done in the Network adapter settings?

Answer (score 0):

Found where the fault was. "service network restart" proved to be the solution